# How to navigate to a specific sheet in Google Sheets based upon a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What I am hoping to do is take the =Now() date that is located on my default sheet and in the Row 1 Column 1 cell and somehow when the sheet is accessed onOpen() have it automatically change the active sheet to the tab that matches the current date.

I am a teacher at a behavior school and I created a digital pointsheet my students are having difficulty navigating. I am hoping that a google script can help me. I have asked around and researched the topic, but have not as of now found something that works. Thanks for your time and insights!

Here is an example sheet of what I would like to have [Example Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FujcvuOYLc9dgc1-l9hLMaE6pRIBppIl2h51xzDP1Ho/edit?usp=sharing)

I feel like the script on this page should work with some tweaking, however I am having difficulty with formatting the date in a way that coincides with the tabs.  Here is the link to the script I have been working with trying to create something that meets my needs.
[Possible Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213555/google-apps-spreadsheet-open-specific-sheet-based-on-current-date-month)

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. By the way, we have several related questions. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+jump+today

Answer (score 0):

When Apps Script read a date from a cell it pass a JavaScript object but the sheet names are strings. You could use [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format).